# Unable to use .map in dropdown menu ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I want to populate the dropdown list with data from the database, disastertype is an array with all the details, however when I map through it to display the disaster_type it does not work, the page does not even renders a blank page is shown. Please guide as I am a beginner with REACTJS.

[image: My page looks something like this]

```
  const [disastertype,Setdisastertype] = useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/disasterinfo").then((response)=>{
      Setdisastertype(response)
      console.log(response)

    })

  },[])
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 <td><div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Disaster Type</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        {disastertype.map((val)=>(
            
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" key={val.disaster_type}>{val.disaster_type}</a></li>
            
        ))}
          </ul>
       
        </div></td>
```

Result from console.log(response)
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EJhn.png)

Comment: Is disastertype an array or object, can you include the object json

Comment: @Azzy    const [disastertype,Setdisastertype] = useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/disasterinfo").then((response)=>{
      Setdisastertype(response)
      console.log(response)

    })

  },[])

Comment: The code seems to be ok, but can you please edit the question and put the code there and also include ouput of the console.log from dev tools, that would help community members give better answers

Comment: When setting the new state for `disastertype` you should use `response.data`

Answer (score 0):

You have just simply missed a field , you have two options here :

1. change `Setdisastertype(response)` to `Setdisastertype(response.data)`
2. change `disastertype.map` to `disastertype.data.map`

First solution is recommended.